# How to determine whether a variable has a positive or negative effect on the model?

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering

I was told that gradient boosting and random forest cannot determine this using the feature importance score. What is the best way to figure this out? And just to make sure, if a variable had a very large negative effect on the model, would it still show up as having high feature importance?

Comment: Because the effects are not assumed to be monotonic, there's no guarantee that it is meaningful to say that the effect of the variable is positive or negative, even if it has high importance.  And yes, variables with very large, consistently negative effects would have high importance.

Comment: But if a variable was monotonic, how would I find out if it's monotonically increasing or decreasing?

Comment: It seems that you are terning the feature-selection as variable selection. I understand that feature denotes a different thing.

Comment: No they're the same thing. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138740/what-is-the-difference-between-independent-variable-and-a-feature